# How to use connect middlware with node.js expess 4?

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-connect

I am still learning node.js and trying to add [connect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect) middleware to this code:

```
var express = require('express')
var hbs = require('express-handlebars');

var connect = require('connect'),
path = require('path'),
hbs = require('express-handlebars');


app = express();
app.engine('handlebars', hbs(
{defaultLayout: 'main',
layoutsDir: app.get('views') + '/layouts',
partialsDir: [app.get('views') + '/partials']
}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3300);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
console.log('Server up: http://localhost:' + app.get('port'));
});
```

However the sample code on connect docs also contains:

```
var app = connect();
```

Which would confilct with what express wants. So I'm wondering how can I have both, so that I can use these middlewares:

```
app.use(connect.json());
app.use(connect.urlencoded());
app.use(connect.methodOverride());
app.use(connect.cookieParser('some-secret-value-here'));
```

I've searched but could not find up-to-date code samples about this.

Comment: You do not use connect with Express any more.  Express has built-in middleware of its own.  You are probably looking at older documentation for an earlier version of Express if `connect` is being used for middleware.

Comment: @jfriend00 That's right. I'm reading a book that uses express3. So how would you add the middleware nowadays?

Comment: Better to go to the [middleware page on the ExpressJS site](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html).  An Express 3.x book is not going to be too helpful when everyone is using 4.x now.  It's just `app.use(function(req, res, next) {...});`.  More examples [here](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.built-in) including using 3rd party middleware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A book that documents Express 3 is going to be misleading in a number of ways when using Express 4 because a lot of the functionality that one used to use Connect for is now built into Express 4.  [The Express JS web site](http://expressjs.com/) is really quite good and you can pretty much see anything you want to about middleware on that site.

For example, here's [a page about the built-in middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.built-in).